# Hibernate cache vs Map - Storage purpose

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, ehcache, second-level-cache

Let say i have a table which has `Master Data` seeded 1 time, and rarely it gets updated. It has a flat structure entity, nothing sort of `Lazy attributes`.

```
Address{
     id,
     country,
     state,
     city,
     pincode,
     area
}
```

> Case -1 : Table has 1000 records
>
> Case-2 : Table has 1 million records

Use Case - Need to get full `Address object` by id. No updation in transaction in this table, just used for display purpose, LOV's, reference Id etc.

1. Considering performance, memory usages, GC, search speed etc which one is better using Hibernate cache(id, object) for this or just using `static HashMap (is as key, Address object as value)`.
2. I know `Hibernate 2nd level cache` (`ehcache`,`Infinispan` etc) also uses Map structure deep inside libraries. So does it add any useful in above cases, to add extra layer of Hibernate.

Comment: are you referring to the first level of hibernate cache on your first point?

Comment: @kucing_terbang no it's purely 2nd level cache vs hashmap in topic, no Ist level

Comment: then I will choose to go with hibernate cache (ehcache, etc). Unless you have a huge memory reserved for JVM.

Comment: @ kucing_terbang Yes, so i want to know how is Hibernate managing objects, isn't storing in-memory..??, how it stores id and object in this case and where, is it purely on disk.

Comment: yes, hibernate will store it into the memory until the transaction has ended (which it will write the data into the database/disk and clean the cache/memory). the treatment should be the same on your case as in the end, the `Address` is just another entity for hibernate.

Comment: @kucing_terbang There will be no updates in this entity, no inserts, only read. If both `HashMap` and `2nd level cache` storing in memory, then what is the diff btw the two.

Comment: Basicallly, 2nd level cache provide you with already made scalability. I mean, if you only use hashmap. You will need to also take care yourself if let say the size of data increase. And to make my last comment more clear. The data is cached in memory but you will need to open the transaction session when you get the data indefinitely then.

Answer (score 1):

**Ehcache ,Hazelcast(for 2nd level cache)** etc  has more features than a static Hashmap.

1.limit the maximum number of elements in memory

2.overflow to disk (if the above number is exceeded)

3.set a time-to-live and time-to-idle for elements

4.allows replication within a cluster

If you want these features then you should go for this.Otherwise static hashmap can do your job. Make it refresh after some time if your records gets updated.

One more thing,in both the cases data will be stored in memory or you can say on Heap. But if you want to store data **OFF Heap** then read about **MapDB**.

I have worked on hazelcast as 2nd level cache provider.It gives distributed cache as well and work well in clustering environments.

Check these links
[Disk based HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654709/disk-based-hashmap)
[Ehcache Vs Static map cache implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120870/ehcache-vs-static-map-cache-implementation)

Comment: But using ``MapDb reading from disk can be a overhead., meaning talking about in memory and having enough memory, `HashMap` can be better.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Its better if you don't want all those cache features as ehcache is giving.